# How to split the image into 4 equal parts and do some processing on each part and then finally merge all the processed image parts?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2;
import math;
import numpy as np;
import image_slicer;
import PIL;
from PIL import Image
import time
import concurrent.futures
import image_slicer
from image_slicer import join


def DCP(im,i):

pil_image = im
opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

src= opencvImage;
I = src.astype('float64')/255;

dark = DarkChannel(I,15);
A = AtmLight(I,dark);
te = TransmissionEstimate(I,A,15);
t = TransmissionRefine(src,te);
J = Recover(I,t,A,0.1);
cv2.imwrite("J"+str(i)+".jpg",J*255);
```

---

```
tiles = image_slicer.slice('o1.jpg', 4, save=False)
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
for tile in tiles:
    results = [executor.submit(DCP,tile.image,i)]
    i=i+1
i=1       
for tile in tiles:
tile.image = Image.open("J"+str(i)+".jpg")
i=i+1

img = join(tiles)
img =img.convert("RGB")
img.save('Dehaze_Parallel.jpg')
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in{round(finish-start,2)} seconds')
```

The ultimate goal is to split the image into 4 parts, process them parallelly using the multiprocessing concept, and then merge the processed all the processed image parts into a single image.

Please refer my comments for more details.

Comment: Could you share an example of your code? From what I understand now, I would create an empty numpy array, and then merge four parts into it. It would also require to know correct place (original indices) for every picture. You might have tried that already, though

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Could you please post the code and show the result that you are getting?
Also, what is the purpose of using multiprocessing here?

Comment: Multiprocessing is required to process the image parallelly and to find the speed up achieved when processing image parallely compared to sequential execution

Comment: @GaneshTata I have added the code snippet and the error message.

Comment: @Oleh Please go through code snippet,which I have added now.

Comment: Are you using PIL or Opencv to read the image? `astype` would work only for numpy array.

Comment: @GaneshTata Yes, Tile.image is passed to DCP function, and Tile.image is of type PIL...and that's why the error message. Now I am converting PIL to openCV and is not getting that error. Though I am still not able to figure out how I would merge the processed image into single image.

Comment: Please update the question if you have resolved the particular error. It might mislead people who want to answer the question. Also did you try @Oleh's suggestion?

Comment: Does this slice the image in half vertically and again in half horizontally? That may not be the best idea from locality of access and cache effects if you think about how images are laid out in memory. It may be better to divide it by drawing 3 horizontal lines rather than 1 vertical and 1 horizontal line. It may also make it easier to work on edge-effects since images will just have horizontal edges not horizontal and vertical.

Comment: I have updated the code. For dividing the image, I am using image_slicer. Which divides the image into 4 parts and the image parts produced(by image_slicer) are of type PIL type. The DCP function(& sub-functions in it) process the image of type  openCV. Therfore, after calling the DCP function, first the image type is changed and the image is processed. With code snippet shared, I am able to process image parallely and then merge the result. The problem with this code is, it is very inefficient and make lots of IO request(for storing parts of image and then retrieving it while merging).

Comment: With the current code, the processing is taking time larger than running the sequential code. Please provide a way to divide the image (other than using image_slicer). If possible please mention the method with example.

Comment: @GaneshTata Please refer the updated code snippet and the my above comments for more details. Please tag a person who can help here.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated the code snippet. And also refer abovemy above comments for more details.

Comment: Why have you removed all the `import` statements? It makes it impossible to run your code. Why are you mixing OpenCV and PIL - you will confuse yourself.

Comment: Where are the various functions defined please? `DarkChannel`, `TransmissionEstimate` ...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added imports. I have not mixed, as mentioned in my previous comment image_slicer after slicing produces image of type PIL. The processing function work on openCV image. Please suggest some other method for slicing the image and then merging it after processing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why do need you other functions ,I have not included it here. Just consider them as black box.

Comment: You are supposed to provide a *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* which you will know if you did the StackOverflow tour. If you don't provide `import` statements, or any images or your functions, it is very hard to help you. How do we know which modules you are using? The answer may be completely different if your image is 320x240 or 20,000x30,000 or if your unspecified functions are simple and only point functions or global filters with large radii.

Comment: I have included all the import statements. Please re-check.

Comment: Can anyone please share the way to split the images and merge images using openCV?